# ORA-01841 while using TO_DATE with null values

Tags: sql, database, string, oracle, date

I have a date column that is formatted as number(10) data type. Some records contain -1 values (null). I would like to format that column to date type. Using the `TO_DATE` function returns this message:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0

Is this caused by the null values? How can avoid that?

```
TO_DATE(TEST.PRELIM_DATE,'YYYYMMDD')`
```

Thank you

Comment: Could u please add some example data

Comment: a negative 1 is not the same as a null

Comment: so if i had a -1, and you wanted that treated as a null, you could do a case -1 then null, then use a nvl() function to replace that null with something like a bogus date of 1/1/1899 or whatever would make sense for your application - or reject the record as invalid

Comment: What are the values in the column? A four digit year?

Comment: Null is Null. -1 is not null. Space is not null. Empty string is not null. etc... I know it's pedantic, but real null handling is something to be careful with.

Comment: I don't get why a year can't be 0 though. What's wrong with the year that Jesus was born?

Comment: @LukStorms - 1 BC/BCE was followed by 1 AD/CE. There is no year zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_zero

Comment: @kfinity Oh it's like that. O_o Thx for the info.

Comment: Why on earth do you store `DATE` as number values?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit because people who developed the software are geniuses ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle function `TO_DATE` does accept `NULL` values (and returns `NULL` in that case). The error that you are getting means that the given value does not match the specified format.

If `-1` is the only invalid value that might show up, just replace it with `NULL`, like :

```
TO_DATE(
    NULLIF(TEST.PRELIM_DATE, -1),
    'YYYYMMDD'
)
```

Starting with Oracle 12.2, another solution is to use the `ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause, like :

```
TO_DATE(
    TEST.PRELIM_DATE,
    'YYYYMMDD'
) DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR
```

This will trap all conversion errors and return `NULL` instead of raising an error (note that this can lead to legitimate errors being masked). From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TO_DATE.html#GUID-D226FA7C-F7AD-41A0-BB1D-BD8EF9440118) :

> The optional `DEFAULT return_value ON CONVERSION ERROR` clause allows you to specify the value this function returns if an error occurs while converting `char` to `DATE`. This clause has no effect if an error occurs while evaluating `char`. The `return_value` can be an expression or a bind variable, and it must evaluate to a character string of `CHAR`, `VARCHAR2`, `NCHAR`, or `NVARCHAR2` data type, or `null`. The function converts `return_value` to `DATE` using the same method it uses to convert `char to DATE. If return_value cannot be converted to DATE`, then the function returns an error.

Comment: Should be noted that `DEFAULT return_value ON CONVERSION ERROR` was introduced in Oracle 12.2 and might not be available yet on every database server.

Comment: I think `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` would be useful anyway in case you have invalid dates like `20190229`

Comment: @GMB it worked using the `NULLIF` function

Many thanks for the prompt response :)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit : thanks for your comment on compatibility `ON CONVERSION ERROR`, I included it in my answer.

Comment: The syntax of using `ON CONVERSION ERROR` is 
`TO_DATE(TEST.PRELIM_DATE DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR,'YYYYMMDD')`